# Parametric plotting on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, finance

I am working on a quantitative finance problem, and I wish to plot the following functions:

mu= 0.1*w+0.14*(1-w) and sigma = (0.12^2)*w^2+0.4*0.12*0.2*2*w(1-w)+(0.2^2)*(1-w)^2;
for w between 0 and 1. I have tried the following code:

```
w=linspace(0,1);
mu= 0.1*w+0.14*(1-w);
sigma = (0.12^2)*w.^2+0.4*0.12*0.2*2*w(1-w)+(0.2^2)*(1-w).^2;
plot(mu,sigma);
xlabel('mu'),ylabel('sigma')
title('risk vs return')
```

And I get the following errors:

> Incorrect dimensions for raising a matrix to a power. Check that the
>   matrix is square and the power is a scalar. To perform elementwise
>   matrix powers, use '.^'.

But when I replaced the "^" for ".^", I got this error

> Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

And I don't know how to proceed. How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you forgot a multiplication in this term **0.4*0.12*0.2*2*w(1-w)**.

```
w=linspace(0,1);
mu= 0.1*w+0.14*(1-w);
sigma = (0.12^2)*w.^2+0.4*0.12*0.2*2*w.*(1-w)+(0.2^2)*(1-w).^2;
plot(mu,sigma);
xlabel('mu'),ylabel('sigma')
title('risk vs return')
```

This worked for me.